# Can not get the text of EditText in a Fragment - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have a `fragment` with 2 `EditTexts`, 2 `TextViews` and 1 `Button`. I tried to get the text entered into the first `EditText` (inputTask1), but always receive `null`.

I tried both `OnCreateView()` and `OnViewCreated()` but nothing works. Thank you!

This is the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_task_list">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Task 1"
            android:id="@+id/inputTask1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputTask2"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Task 2"
            android:id="@+id/inputTask2"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputTask1" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/saveButton"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/saveButton" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputTask2" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewTask1"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="Task 1 name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/viewTask1" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/saveButton" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewTask2"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="Task 2 name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/viewTask2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewTask1" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the fragment file:

```
package com.example.repetodo

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_tasklist.view.*

class TaskListFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        var view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasklist, container, false)
        view.saveButton.setOnClickListener{view ->
            Log.i("TaskListFragment","Button is clicked")
            val editText = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputTask1)
            Log.i("TaskListFragment","the EditText ${editText}")
            Log.i("TaskListFragment","the text ${view.inputTask1?.text}")
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```

The result in Logcat is:

```
I/TaskListFragment: Button is clicked
I/TaskListFragment: the EditText null
I/TaskListFragment: the text null
```

Comment: You're getting variables named `view` mixed up. Inside the `OnClickListener`, `view` is the `View` being clicked, which will be `saveButton`, and it doesn't contain your `EditText`, so `findViewById()` returns null. The simplest fix is probably to just rename the `OnClickListener`'s `view`; e.g., `setOnClickListener{v ->`.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!